# how to track point on object with rotation

Tags: c++, mathematics

I'm working on a top down shooter in C++ and need to have a fire point on the player and npc's so that when they rotate bullets come out of the fire point and not the actual position

here's what i mean(red is the fire point):

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Google the `atan2` function. May be what you need.

Comment: Or the unit circle (cos, sin) if you're going the opposite direction, from an angle to a vector. We have existing Q&A explaining each of these tools.

Comment: So, given an angle, you're trying to compute the offset of the point, correct?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
offset_x = cos(angle) * radius
offset_y = sin(angle) * radius
```

This is the offset of the red point relative to the center of the circle.

For `angle = 0` this results in `offset_x = radius, offset_y = 0`, and for `angle = pi/2` the result is `offset_x = 0, offset_y = radius`. This is merely a convention, and by swapping `sin` and `cos`, or negating one or both offsets, or negating angle, it's possible to invert the rotation direction and/or change what direction `angle = 0` represents.